# Sitecore: importing a sublayout after deploying the code

Tags: import, sitecore, sublayout

I have a local Sitecore instance where I made changes involving both code and the creation of a new sublayout.

After deploying the code I can see on the new environment the usercontrol (.ascx) file associated to the sublayout, but the corresponding item does not appear and cannot be used.

If I attempt to recreate the usercontrol, it tells me that the file already exists, and due to my lack of experience with the platform I found myself unable to import it.

What would be the optimal way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy your new sublayout correctly you should create a Sitecore Package. This is basically a zip file that allows you to move both items and disk files between Sitecore instances in a controlled manner. For basic installs of Sitecore, where you have not added any specialised tools, it is generally the preferred way to move resources between servers.

The "Package Designer Guide" on the Sitecore Developer Network will give you information about how to use the Sitecore UI on your development site to create a package containing both the Item(s) and the file(s) for your sublayout:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/package_designer_admin_guide-a4.pdf

Once created, this package can then be imported onto whatever other servers you want to deploy your sublayout to.

-- Edited to add --

Derek Hunziker's answer makes a good point: As well as the basic Sitecore behaviour there are third party tools available which can enhance and extend the deployment experience if you wish. As well as Hedgehog TDS, you might also consider:

The "Sitecore Rocks" extension for Visual Studio allows the creation of packages from within the 
Visual Studio UI. This tool is free to use. (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44a26c88-83a7-46f6-903c-5c59bcd3d35b/)

There are also a variety of open source tools - Sitecore Courier is one example: (https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Courier) This is designed to help automate deployment between Sitecore instances.

Both TDS and Courier are most suited to regular deployments, such as those during ongoing development cycles, since they both include automation to help decide what gets deployed. The standard Sitecore UI and the Sitecore Rocks extensions for package creation are better suited to ad-hoc deployments, since you generally pick the things to deploy manually.

Comment: Thank you, will try this route first.

Answer (score 2):

A common best practice is to deploy your items along with your code using [Team Development for Sitecore](http://www.hhogdev.com/products/team-development-for-sitecore/overview.aspx). This eliminates the need to create Sitecore packages every time you want to move items between environments, which in turn reduces issues caused by human error. As an added bonus, the items that you own as a developer (such as Templates and SubLayouts) can be checked into source control.

Full disclosure: I work for Hedgehog Development :)